# Scene slowly rotating away

Tags: android, opengl-es

In my GLSurfaceView.Renderer, I'm drawing my scene in two parts.  The first group is offset and rotated, while the second is aligned to the "camera", so I apply a glRotate and glTranslate, then apply the exact opposite glTranslate and glRotate.  On some devices, this works fine, but on others, the entire scene slowly rotates off "center".

Images: [At start](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-KSeOa8SNIBs/UN0uhxyC6GI/AAAAAAAAHdE/soLR-RaMSBg/s898/Screenshot_2012-12-27-23-54-48.png) and [After ~5 mins](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-lCRJ7Y0NS7c/UN0uh9vP6VI/AAAAAAAAHdA/TDBn2tHtrvc/s898/Screenshot_2012-12-27-23-54-40.png)

Here's the onDraw() function:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    // rotate card table
    gl.glRotatef(-20f, 1f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glRotatef(  5f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    gl.glRotatef(-10f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glTranslatef( 1f, 3f, 0f);

    mDeck.draw(gl);

    // undo rotate for buttons/overlays
    gl.glTranslatef(-1f, -3f, 0f);
    gl.glRotatef( 10f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glRotatef( -5f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    gl.glRotatef( 20f, 1f, 0f, 0f);

    mOverlayBtns.draw(gl);
    mPass.draw(gl);
}
```

The full source can be found on GitHub, [here.](https://github.com/VoteBrian/smoke-or-fire)

Is there something obvious I'm missing?  Is there a better way to handle rotating, then rotating back?

So far, I've noticed this problem on:

- Nexus 4
- HTC Sensation
- Another LG phone whose name I can't remember

These devices do not show the problem:

- Galaxy Nexus
- Nexus 7
- Xoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was applying a set of affine transformations each frame, the problem is that each transformation is accumulative, so you were applying the transformation over and over. You either need to reset the current loaded MODELVIEW matrix using glLoadIdentity (http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glLoadIdentity.xml) or push the current matrix, load your new matrix, draw and then pop the matrix back (as you were doing in your fix response).

I would put a glLoadIdentity at the beginning of each frame draw. Also, with your fix, I would also do this:

```
gl.glPushMatrix();

gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Be sure we start clean

// rotate card table
gl.glRotatef(-20f, 1f, 0f, 0f);
gl.glRotatef(  5f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
gl.glRotatef(-10f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
gl.glTranslatef( 1f, 3f, 0f);

mDeck.draw(gl);

gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a fix for the issue, but I'm still hoping someone will be able to explain the problem I'm seeing above.

Instead of rotating the scene, then rotating back, I can use glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix to isolate the two groups.  That way, the group of glTranslate and glRotate to move the scene back are unnecessary.

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


    gl.glPushMatrix();

    // rotate card table
    gl.glRotatef(-20f, 1f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glRotatef(  5f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    gl.glRotatef(-10f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glTranslatef( 1f, 3f, 0f);

    mDeck.draw(gl);

    gl.glPopMatrix();


    gl.glPushMatrix();
    // undo rotate for buttons/overlays
    // gl.glTranslatef(-1f, -3f, 0f);
    // gl.glRotatef( 10f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    // gl.glRotatef( -5f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    // gl.glRotatef( 20f, 1f, 0f, 0f);

    mOverlayBtns.draw(gl);
    mPass.draw(gl);

    gl.glPopMatrix();
}
```